# C++ read in two numbers but no spaces, RINEX file

Tags: c++, file-io, int, double, filestream

I am trying to read in multiple numbers from lines in a RINEX file. The file number looks something like:

12345.67890

However, because of the RINEX formatting the 12345.6789 represents a measurement and the 0 at the end of the decimal actually represents something else. I am using the basic way to read in:

```
Rinexfile>>double_temp;
```

and I get double_temp=12345.67890 where I would like to do

```
Rinexfile>>double_temp>>int_temp;
```

and have double_temp=12345.6789 and int_temp=0. The formatting is always the same, ie 4 decimals belonging to the double and then an int and I am using VS2010

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more sophisticated approach:

```
std::string word;
Rinexfile >> word;
std::size_t dot_pos = str.find('.');
if (dot_pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::string doublePart = word.substr(0, dot_pos + 1 + 4);  // 4 decimals
    std::string intPart = word.substr(dot_pos + 1 + 4);
    std::istringstream is(doublePart), is2(intPart);
    is >> double_temp;
    is2 >> int_temp;
}
```

This reads an input in form of single `std::string` and divides it into 2 parts: `doublePart` is a string that includes `'.'` sign and 4 letters that follows. `intPart` is the rest of the word. Temporary instances of `std::istringstream` are constructed to retrieve the values.

*Note: Additional error handling might be needed.*

Comment: How could I test this method if it is only 3 decimals. What happens now if I make word 123.456 it throws so what I would like to is basically break it into an if, if(word>3 decimals) else

Answer (score 1):

The default input format for floating points will read as many digits after the decimal point as there are. However, it is possible to change the functions used to parse the values by using a custom `std::num_get<char>` facet and installing a suitable locale. Here is how this could roughly look (currently I can't easily test the code):

```
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

struct num_get
    : std::num_get<char>
{
    iter_type do_get(iter_type it, iter_type end, std::ios_base& fmt,
                     std::ios_base::iostate& err, double& value) const {
        char buf[64];
        char* to(buf), to_end(buf + 63);
        for (; it != end && to != to_end
             && std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)); ++it, ++to) {
            *to = *it;
        }
        if (it != end && *it == '.') {
            *to = *it;
            ++it;
            ++to;
        }
        to_end = to_end - to < 4? to_end - to: to + 4;
        for (; it != end && to != to_end
             && std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)); ++it, ++to) {
            *to = *it;
        }
        *to = 0;
        if (std::strtod(buf, 0, &value) != to) {
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
        }
        return it;
    }
};
```

With this decoder (which may want to get a bit more error checking, though) you'd just set up you stream and then read as normal:

```
in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new num_get));
double dval;
int    ival;
if (in >> dval >> ival) {
    std::cout << "read dval=" << dval << " ival=" << ival << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with strings, you could read integral and decimal part separately and get the data you need like this:
    int i, d;

```
cin >> i;
cin.get();  // skip decimal point
cin >> d;

double value = i + (d / 10) / 10000.0;
int something_else = d % 10;

cout << setprecision(4) << fixed << value << endl << something_else;
```

(it won't work if "something else" can be longer than 1 digit)